# SO helpful flags stat appears under "meta participation" statistics for moderator candidate listings

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, election

Each moderator election candidate's stats appear as follows (example chosen at random):

> meta participation
>
> questions: 7 / +30
>
> answers: 17 / +73
>
> helpful flags: 750

However, this can be slightly misleading, as the flags displayed under "meta participation" is the candidate's **Stack Overflow** flag count, not their **Meta** Stack Overflow flag count.

I acknowledge this is a fairly trivial matter, but to prevent confusion, I would suggest fully qualifying this statistic to be more clear, and/or perhaps placing a light horizontal rule between the answers line and the flag weight line.

Comment: If you have 750 flag weight on Meta, *wow*.

Comment: @sixlettervariables: Sounds like the source of a "I'm so meta..." joke.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think adding a horizontal rule would work, but seeing as there's already a number of different shades of grey used in that page, and that the page already has its fair share of horizontal rules, I feel like it would work better just to order them differently:

> helpful flags: 750
>
> meta participation
>
> questions: 7 / +30
>
> answers: 17 / +73

Answer (score 6):

Or:

> helpful flags: 750
>
> meta questions: 7 / +30
>
> meta answers: 17 / +73