# Are people really doing this much flagging on meta?

Tags: support, status-declined, election

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SO flag weight appears under “meta participation” statistics for moderator candidate listings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112136/so-flag-weight-appears-under-meta-participation-statistics-for-moderator-candi)

Are people really doing this much flagging on meta? Or is this not meta participation? Kind of confusing.

[image: GET A DESIGNER]

Comment: I think those are flags on SO.

Comment: Yep.  Those are flags on SO.

Comment: Related: [SO flag weight appears under “meta participation” statistics for moderator candidate listings](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112136/so-flag-weight-appears-under-meta-participation-statistics-for-moderator-candi) - except it's not flag weight anymore

Comment: It IS misleading

Comment: status-declined? Is this some sort of inside joke?